# Why is my github classrooms not loading in vscode?

Tags: github, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use github classrooms in vscode but the extension just has classrooms loading. I used it a while ago without any issues and to my knowledge I don't think anything has changed that wouldn't make it work. I am signed into github on vscode and most other stuff works.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmBQS.png)

I have tried by signing out and signing back in everywhere. Uninstalled and reinstalled git and github desktop as well as vscode extensions.